# How to monitor individual SSL sites being served on IIS6 with host headers and a single IP address?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6

This may be a known issue - but I'm serving 50+ IIS websites using a single IP and multiple unique host headers on an IIS6/Windows 2003 Server.

Problem is with **monitoring**. If a particular site goes down or is STOPPED, the HTTP monitor still reports the site is UP -- I'm assuming because the request just falls to the next site 'in line' or maybe the first site that can serve the request.  **So site A will see site B's content.**

This not only affect monitoring, but can allow one customer to see another customer's login screen!  Is there any way -- aside from giving each site a unique IP address that I can stop this from happening?  I read this related question, and still don't know how to resolve. I want Site A to actually be DOWN when I stop the site -- not just fall back to another site.

**UPDATE**: Site also uses SSL, but no host header shows in the UI.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Stopping websites... what did you want to happen?

The fall-through behaviour is probably this:

- if there's a site binding which is a specific match, show that site
- if not, if there's a less specific site binding which still matches, show that site
- if not, show nothing

I don't know which HTTP monitor or how it works, so I'm focusing on the browser behaviour you describe involving "the wrong logon page".

I expect:

- If *all* your sites have host headers, I'd expect this issue to go away, it'll behave broadly how you'd expect (404 or 5XX response when requesting a disabled site).
- But if *any* site binding includes a non-host-headered IP address, and no host header, that'll be the "default" site for that IP address, and the request will fall through to it.

This gets easier in IIS 8+ with Server Name Indication allowing specific SSL bindings, but it's still a variation on the same principle - if no names match specifically but the IP is correct, you get the IP binding.

Comment: Stopping sites was just a TEST to see that I would actually get a 404 in the browser -- or not available.  The issue is that I still get content from a different site on the server.  So presumably -- if I had monitoring in place, I would never get a DOWN alert.